# Which is the correct capability in Courier SMTP config to get user's password (encryption type)

Tags: mysql, password, encryption, query, courier-imap

MySql: 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

I have followed this guide: [Postfix With Courier IMAP Mail Server Installation](https://classfactory.com/mail-server/postfix-with-courier-imap-mail-server-installation/) (unfortunately they do not answer questions).

I had to change the encryption method for the user's password because the one recommended in the tutorial is rejected by MySql server: `dbname.encrypt does not exist`

Recommended user creation query:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, name, maildir, crypt) VALUES
('postbox@yourdomain.com', 'postbox_yourdomain_com',
 'yourdomain.com/postbox/',
 encrypt('loginpwd', CONCAT('$5$', MD5(RAND()))) 
);
```

Modified user creation query:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `maildir`, `crypt`) VALUES
('postbox@domain.com', 'Mr. Postbox',
'domain.com/postbox/',
SHA2('loginpwd', 256));
```

With the modified query I got the user created but, unfortunately, Courier is not able to understand the password encryption.

In file `/etc/courier/imapd`, next line is found:

```
IMAP_CAPABILITY_ORIG="IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=CRAM-SHA1 AUTH=CRAM-SHA256 IDLE"
```

where I have added the `AUTH=CRAM-SHA256` capability, which does not work....

So, I am looking for the correct capability statement to be added to the `imapd` configuration for Courier so that users can authenticate...

Thanks in advance!!